# How to make your own LaTeX math symbol?

Tags: latex

How do you make your own LaTeX math symbol?  Is it possible?

Comment: If your symbol is a combination of other symbols the answer is straight-forward.

Comment: @Geoff : "the answer is straight-foward". Well, maybe for you!!! Why don't you elaborate? Post an answer and explain how this can be done. It will probably be useful for someone. The way you said, though, is not.

Comment: @Vivi, Looks like `qbi` beat me to it. I wasn't sure from OP's question if this is what was desired. There was another comment about making symbols from curves before my comment.

Comment: @Geoff: It might not be what he is asking, but see, I certainly learned from qbi's answer! Thanks for replying  :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about tex (but is too old to migrate).

Answer (score 7):

Of course you can. May be you can describe what kind of symbol you need. However it might be a good idea to have a look at [LaTeX Comprehensive Symbol List](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) or to try to find your symbol at [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/). One example for a symbol is:

```
\newcommand*{\dotcup}{\ensuremath{\mathaccent\cdot\cup}}
```

it shows

[a \cap with a dot in it http://kubieziel.de/tmp/dotcup.png](http://kubieziel.de/tmp/dotcup.png)

Comment: It's worth mentioning that a guide for creating new symbols is in the chapter “10 Additional Information/3 Where can I find the symbol for . . . ?” of the document mentioned above. Not a straight-forward title at all. ☺

Comment: @beroal That is the [LaTeX Comprehensive Symbol List](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) (first link above), meanwhile Section 12.3, still titled: "Where can I find the symbol for...?".